# Navigation menu is transparent, but i'm not sure why. I want a background

Tags: html, css, background, transparent

1. I'm using a wordpress template.
2. I have just added particles.js as my background.
3. Now my navigation menu is taking the same color as my background, but i want it to be a different color. (I have defined the color in my code but its not working)

Here is the codes i'm using and what i'm seeing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W52DH.jpg

```css
.main-nav {
    background-color: #585858;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#585858), to(#3d3d3d));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #585858, #3d3d3d);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#585858, endColorstr=#3d3d3d)";
}
```

Comment: without code is difficult to guess , but try to position:relative; z-index:100;

Comment: `Here is the codes i'm using and what i'm seeing.`  -- No that's an **image** of your code, and what you are seeing.   You should be pasting *actual* `CSS` and `HTML`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```